# PL/SQL functions leads to "No more data to read from socket error"

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I wrote two function to convert datatype in Oracle, and called these in a select statement on a huge table like this:

```
SELECT
safe_to_number(sid_day) sid_day, 
safe_to_number(albumid) album_id,
safe_to_number(sid_album) sid_album,
safe_to_number(sid_artist) sid_artist,
safe_to_number(sid_channel) sid_channel 
FROM big_table_with_data;
```

after the database has been running for some time, I got a "No more data to read from socket error", and I need to restart Oracle SQL developer to again get access to the database.

Why does this error occur, and is there a way to write PL/SQL functions to avoid this error?

The functions I have implemented are:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
safe_to_number (p varchar2)
RETURN number
IS
retval number;

BEGIN
  IF p IS NULL THEN
   retval := null;
  ELSE
    retval := safe_to_number(p);
  END IF;
  return retval;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Could not change value to number');
    retval := null;
    return retval;

END;
```

and

```
create or replace function is_a_timestamp
    ( p_str in varchar2
      , p_mask in varchar2)
    return timestamp
is
    d date;
begin
    d := to_timestamp(p_str, p_mask);
    return d;
exception
    when others then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Could not change value to timestamp');
    return null;
end;
```

Comment: Do you really mean `safe_to_number()` to be calling itself recursively, forever? Or is it supposed to be calling `to_number()`? If this is what you really have I'd guess the DB server is killing your session because it runs out of resources...

Comment: No, I don't mean to do that, but I now see where the problem is created. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At line 11 of function `safe_to_number` you are recursively calling function `safe_to_number` itself.

This line:

```
retval := safe_to_number(p);
```

should probably be:

```
retval := to_number(p);
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see why that caused a problem.